# Azure Stream Analytics–Querying JSON Arrays of arrays

Tags: arrays, azure-stream-analytics

I have a problem writing a query to extract a table out of the arrays from a json file:
The problem is how to get the information of the array “data packets” and its contents of arrays and then make them all in a normal sql table.

One hard issue there is the "CrashNotification" and "CrashMaxModuleAccelerations", I dont know how to define and use them.

The file looks like this:

---

```
    { "imei": { "imei": "351631044527130F", "imeiNotEncoded":                         
"351631044527130" 
}, 
"dataPackets": [ [ "CrashNotification", { "version": 1, "id": 28 } ], [ 
"CrashMaxModuleAccelerations", { "version": 1, "module": [ -1243, -626, 
14048 ] } ] ]}
```

---

I tried to use Get array elements method and other ways but I am never able to access 2nd level arrays like elements of "CrashNotification" of the "dataPackets" or elements of "module" of the array "CrashMaxModuleAccelerations" of the "dataPackets".

I looked also here ([Select the first element in a JSON array in Microsoft stream analytics query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503674/select-the-first-element-in-a-json-array-in-microsoft-stream-analytics-query?answertab=votes#tab-top)) and it doesnt work.
I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your schema, here's an example of query that will extract a table with the following columns: emei, crashNotification_version, crashNotification_id

```
WITH Datapackets AS
(
SELECT imei.imei as imei,
        GetArrayElement(Datapackets, 0) as CrashNotification
FROM input
)
SELECT  
    imei,
    GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(CrashNotification, 1), 'version') as crashNotification_version,
    GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(CrashNotification, 1), 'id') as crashNotification_id
FROM Datapackets
```

Let me know if you have any further question.

Thanks,

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)

Comment: Dear JS Azure, would you please have a look on this question, your feedback would be highly appreciated :)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141061/azure-stream-analytics-error-with-customized-timestamp-by-while-applying-win

Comment: @AhmedEssam: sorry I missed your message initially. I saw one of our team member already answer the thread. Hope you are now unblocked.

Answer (score -1):

We built a HTTP API called [Stride](http://www.stride.io) for converting streaming JSON data into realtime, incrementally updated tables using only SQL.

All you'd need to do is write raw JSON data to the Stride API's [/collect](https://www.stride.io/docs#collect) endpoint, define continuous SQL queries via the [/process](https://www.stride.io/docs#process) endpoint, and then push or pull data via the [/analyze](https://www.stride.io/docs#analyze) endpoint.

This approach eliminates the need to deal with any underlying data infrastructure and gives you a SQL-based approach to this type of streaming analytics problem.

Comment: This URL is now used for a career profile product. It appears this HTTP API no longer exists.