# Azure Stream Analytics - Error with customized "timestamp by" while applying window tumbling

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have a json file as below:

> {"imei": {"imei": "358174069248418F", "imeiBinary": "NYF0BpJIQY8=","imeiNotEncoded": "358174069248418","valid": 1},"dataPackets": [["msy.mxp.datapacket.AlarmNotification",{"version": 1, "id": 21, "op": 2,"sizeDynamic": 0, "alarmStatus": 4}],["msy.mxp.datapacket.IOStatus",{"version": 1,"id": 15, "op": 2,"sizeDynamic": 0,"ioStatus": 135,"ioDirections": 120}], ["msy.mxp.datapacket.LogicalStatus",{"version": 1,"id": 16, "op": 2,"sizeDynamic": 0,"logicalStatus": 5} ],[ "msy.mxp.datapacket.Position", {"version": 1,"id": 19,"op": 2,"latitude": 40.835243,"longitude": 14.246057,"altitude": 40,"speed": 0, "course": 68, "gpsNumSatellite": 5,"glonassNumSatellite": 1,"fixValid": 1,"timeValid": 1,"wgs84degMinFormat": 1, "glonass": 1,"fixMode": 3,"timestamp": {"timeSecFrom1Gen2000": 925560202,"time": 1490648755000 }, "sizeDynamic": 0} ] ]}

and I am reading by the following query:

```
WITH Datapackets AS
(
SELECT imei.imei as imei,
        persistent as persistent,
        [timestamp].[time] as input_time,
        compressed as compressed,
        GetArrayElement(dataPackets, 3) as position
FROM h24
), one as(
SELECT *,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'timestamp') as position_timestamp --1st
from Datapackets 
), two as (
select
    imei,
    GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'op') as position_OP,
    [position_timestamp].[time] as position_time,
    dateadd(S, [position_timestamp].[timeSecFrom1Gen2000], '1970-01-01') as timing,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'latitude') as position_latitude,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'longitude') as position_longitude,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'altitude') as position_altitude,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'speed') as position_speed
    from one) SELECT * from two
```

Now I want to make window tumbling group by 30 seconds as following but I have a problem which tells me that timestamp property is not allowed for the input file"two" ,, here the query that I use

```
    WITH Datapackets AS
    (
    SELECT imei.imei as imei,
            persistent as persistent,
            [timestamp].[time] as input_time,
            compressed as compressed,
            GetArrayElement(dataPackets, 3) as position
    FROM h24
    ), one as(
    SELECT *,
    GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'timestamp') as position_timestamp --1st
    from Datapackets 
    ), two as (
    select
        imei,
        GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'op') as position_OP,
        [position_timestamp].[time] as position_time,
        dateadd(S, [position_timestamp].[timeSecFrom1Gen2000], '1970-01-01') as timing,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'latitude') as position_latitude,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'longitude') as position_longitude,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'altitude') as position_altitude,
GetRecordPropertyValue (GetArrayElement(position,1), 'speed') as position_speed
        from one) SELECT imei, System.TimeStamp AS 'start', Avg(position_speed), max(position_latitude)  
FROM two TIMESTAMP BY TIMING GROUP BY imei, TumblingWindow(duration(second, 30))
```

The error appears in the last two lines (FROM two TIMESTAMP BY TIMING),

************** Update,, After investigating more, I found that I can only use the option timestamp by in the input, and I have to use it only if I will make customized timestamping for the events. Normally they are timestamped by the arrival time as default (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt573293.aspx)

Now my problem is how to timestamp my events with a time field that is recorded in a 3rd level array in the Json file to be able to do my aggregation.

Any suggestions about how I deal with this problem, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598501.aspx `TIMESTAMP BY` can only be used on input sources, so you would want to put that as part of your very first step:

```
WITH Datapackets AS
...
FROM h24 TIMESTAMP BY (expression)
...
```

Furthermore, from the same source, referring to `System.TimeStamp` when used with a `GROUP BY` over a window:

> The timestamp of the result of the aggregate is the end of the time window to which this result corresponds.

So when you write `System.TimeStamp` in the final `SELECT` statement, it refers to the end of the current window.

Comment: Thanks runemoennike for your comment, it helped me to understand.   After investigating more, I found that I can only use the option timestamp by in the input, and I have to use it only if I will make customized timestamping for the events. Normally they are timestamped by the arrival time as default (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt573293.aspx)

Now my problem is how to timestamp my events with a time field that is recorded in a 3rd level array in the Json file to be able to do my aggregation.

Comment: Have you tried `FROM h24 TIMESTAMP BY GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(GetArrayElement(dataPackets, 3) ,1), 'timestamp')` ?

Although I must add that it's a very unstable solution, since it relies on the order of the array always being the same.

A better way might be to set up a flow where a Function App reads from the input event/IoT hub, reformats to a more appropriate arrangement, and then pushes events to another hub from which your stream analytics query pulls out events.

Comment: Indeed as you said, it will not be useful to use that expression of the time stamp by "***"  because of the different structure of incoming arrays. However Ill think about the other option. Thank you very much

Comment: The best way to parse such complex events is custom JavaScript function. Unfortunately JavaScript functions are not allowed in TIMESTAMP BY expression. You may want to consider splitting this into two queries - one without TIMESTAMP BY that "normalizes" the data and extracts required fields, and second query that uses TIMESTAMP BY and performs window aggregate

Comment: That could be a good idea  Konstantin, by what do you mean by splitting the query into two, do you mean to have another stream analytics job with a query that receives the normalized data from the first one and then to do the time stamping, if you refer to that, I already tried this option and it is working but I faced a new problem which is the second stream job receives for instance 100K events but gives out only 5 or 6 outputs, and no error reported !! If you mean something else, please let me know, I am new to this subject. Thank you :)

Comment: You should probably make a new question for that, if you want to go that way, so you can post your code and we can look at it. 5-6 outputs could be correct, depending on the window and the timestamps of said events.