# Java-script user defined function in azure stream analytics for grouping by time intervals

Tags: javascript, azure, user-defined-functions, azure-stream-analytics

In Azure stream analytics job,I have a SELECT query that gives me output in the following structure:

ASA Output Structure

[image: ASA output structure]

I would like to do a group by time intervals of 15 seconds getting average speed, and last Lat/Longitudes. I managed to do it via AZA query but I cant make it in the same Query job with the previous SELECT Statement due the "timestamp by" properties in ASA.

So I think an option could be to have a Java-script user defined function to do so.

This is the ASA query for the aggregation that I have and I want similar UDF:

```
with one as (SELECT
    [imei],[timing],[position_latitude],[position_longitude],[position_speed],
    CAST(LAST([position_latitude]) OVER ( partition by imei LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1) WHEN position_latitude IS NOT NULL) as float ) as Lst_lat,
    CAST(LAST([position_longitude]) OVER ( partition by imei LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1) WHEN position_longitude IS NOT NULL ) as float ) as Lst_lon
FROM
    eventhublevelII TIMESTAMP BY Timing )

SELECT imei, System.Timestamp as Time_Group,
AVG(POSITION_SPEED) as AVG_SPEED,
max(Lst_lat) as last_lat,
max(Lst_lon) as last_lon
into SQL
from one 
GROUP BY imei, TumblingWindow(second, 30)
```

It is reading from this file:

> {"imei":"351631046708985F","position_op":2,"position_time":1490603299000,"timing":"2017-03-27T08:28:19.0000000Z","position_latitude":0.0,"position_longitude":0.0,"position_altitude":180,"position_speed":0,"position_course":0,"position_glonass":1,"position_gpsnumsatellite":0,"position_glonassnumsatellite":0,"position_fixvalid":0,"position_timevalid":1,"position_wgs84degminformat":1,"position_fixmode":1}

The desired output is as in this table:

Aggregation Table Output

[image: aggregation table output]

Any Ideas or suggestions  would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working with "timestamp by" properties in ASA? It is not very clear form your question.

Comment: I want to use the events real time which is stored in a 3rd level array, and it can not be done in the first SELECT Statement. I mentioned this problem here in this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141061/azure-stream-analytics-error-with-customized-timestamp-by-while-applying-win                                      Let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: I added comment to your other thread: you can consider splitting your query into 2 - one without TIMESTAMP BY that "normalizes" the data and extracts required fields, and second query that uses TIMESTAMP BY and performs window aggregate